# Do resistances granted by scrolls of wish count against the magic item cap?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, dnd-adventurers-league, damage-resistance

During Season 8 of the Adventurers' League, *spell scrolls* of [*wish*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/wish) were relatively easy to acquire as a tier 3+ adventurer. Many characters who dipped into Wizard or Sorcerer would purchase these scrolls to gain resistance to a damage type of their choice.

When Season 9 started, a new guidance was the to the FAQ regarding persistent effects. According the [Adventurers' League FAQ](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/208178/DD-Adventurers-League-Players-Pack) (v.9.1):

> **Items With Persistent Effects**
>
> You can only benefit from a magic item
>   that grants the same permanent benefit once (e.g., *tome of
>   understanding*, *bag of beans*, etc.). This guidance is retroactive.
>   Further, items that bestowed a persistent effect (such as a *manual of
>   golems*, via *wish*es from *luck blade*s, etc.) count against that
>   character’s Magic Item Limit for as long as they retain the
>   benefit—even if they don’t own the item or it has lost its magical
>   properties. You can choose to replace or abandon the item as normal,
>   but in so doing, the benefits it conveyed (resistance to damage,
>   ability score increases, etc.) are lost.

Do *spell scroll*s of *wish* that were used to acquire resistance to a damage type now count against a character's Magic Item Limit, even though they're consumable magic items?

Answer (score 1):

## Resistances granted by scrolls of *Wish* do not count against the magic item cap.

The rules concerning a permanent effect which makes a magic item always count towards the cap is under a chapter specifically referring to the permanent magic item count.

Additionally, in page 7 of the Adventurers League Frequently Asked Questions it clarifies that scrolls are consumable so would not apply to that count.